# docker-compose service for running tests not working properly

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle, testing, docker-compose

I am building spring boot app and I am trying to setup a docker-compose for running the tests only, but when trying to run the `tests` service it runs the application, it seems that the `command: /app/gradlew clean test --info` is being ignored or maybe I am doing this wrong?..
Any thoughts on what may be causing this?
Thank you

Dockerfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:debian-slim as BUILD_IMAGE

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# COPY dependencies
#COPY scripts $APP_HOME/script
COPY build.gradle.kts $APP_HOME
COPY settings.gradle.kts $APP_HOME
COPY src $APP_HOME/src
ADD gradlew $APP_HOME
ADD gradle $APP_HOME/gradle

# Build
RUN $APP_HOME/gradlew clean build -x test

# Final Docker Image
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:debian-slim
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /app/build/libs/application.jar /app/

# Expose the desired port
EXPOSE 8080

# Define the command to run your application
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/application.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - env_vars.env
  
  tests:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/mydatabase
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=user
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=pass
    command: /app/gradlew clean test --info

  postgres:
    image: postgres:11.2
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
      POSTGRES_DB: mydatabase
```

Answer (score 0):

You've used `ENTRYPOINT` to specify your main application command, and then the `tests` container is setting the `command:`.  This causes the `mvn` command to get passed as arguments to your application; see the [Understand how CMD and ENTRYPOINT interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) section in the Dockerfile documentation.

I'd recommend changing `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` in the Dockerfile.  This makes a couple of tasks easier, like running a debugging shell over the image, and supports an *entrypoint wrapper script* pattern to do startup-time tasks like dynamically setting environment variables or running database migrations.

You can also change `command:` to `entrypoint:` in the Compose file.  The important thing is that what's being overridden matches where the command is actually provided in the Dockerfile.